# Search JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying do a search script in JavaScript

It should get the HTML content of multiple URLs and search a string in it, if it matches, save the content of the page in a HTML file.

I have some problem with that. Why?

Well, it gets the content of the first URL, but it doesn't get the content of the specified URL in the next search.

Here is the code:

```
var i = 24522460;

function startSearch(){
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var fs = require('fs');

    page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
        console.log(msg)
        return;
    };

    page.open('http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/principal.html?ir=cpnev_csni&tp=1&ci='+i, function () {
        console.log(i);
        if(page.content.search('RICARDO')>=0)
            //console.log(page.content);
        fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
        shiftPage();
    }); 
}

function shiftPage(){
    i++;
    startSearch();
}

startSearch();
```

If you want to prove it, in the `i=24522469` it should save the HTML file.

Comment: It seems like you're writing to the same file each time (`1.html`). Are you sure it's not reading multiple URLs, then overwriting the contents? And is this running in the browser, in node.js, or where?

Comment: Yes, because when it start from 24522460 (It no find 'RICARDO' in content and don't save the file, and when it 24522469 (should find 'RICARDO? in the content) but it don't that.

Comment: Try something like `fs.write(i + '.html', page.content, 'w')` so at each search it makes a new file with the same number of the (I believe i represents an ID ) Id.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i do that and i see what's the problem, the problem was on fast request of the script and the page don't load completly, i put an delay on this and works fine!

Comment: shouldn't you be iterating the page numbers? rather than '1.html', use something like `fs.write((i+'.html'), page.content, 'w');` ?

Comment: Yes, i use that, and comment the condition to save the html file to save all the pages, and i can see that the pages are incomplete and bucause that don't find the specified text.

Comment: That's a very interesting thing to point. You should answer your own question mentioning that load issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

The problem was that the script request the page very fast and it don't load complete, because that the script don't find the text specified

I just add an "delay" after load and then search the text and it's works

Thanks for help.